# Can I open invisible forms in VB6

Tags: vb6

I want to perform some actions automatically,
And the best way to make sure everything happens as it is done by hand, would be to open the existing form, do the changes in the form, and call the same function contained in one of the forms button.

So I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without the user seeing anything?(seeing some windows flickering is ok)

Comment: Extract the common code to a module, then call the function in the module from both the form's button handler and the new code. This is one of the benefits of separating your business logic from your presentation code.

Comment: Comintern's approach is much better than this, but you can load the forms off-screen. Say maybe form.left = -10000.

Answer (score 0):

From Help

> **Load Statement**
>
> Loads a form or control into memory.
>
> **Syntax**

```
Load object
```

> The object placeholder is the name of a Form object, MDIForm object, or control array element to load.
>
> **Remarks**
>
> You don't need to use the Load statement with forms unless you want to load a form without displaying it. Any reference to a form (except in a Set or If...TypeOf statement) automatically loads it if it's not already loaded. For example, the Show method loads a form before displaying it. Once the form is loaded, its properties and controls can be altered by the application, whether or not the form is actually visible. Under some circumstances, you may want to load all your forms during initialization and display them later as they're needed.